# sql query to convert string to array and then compare with some condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named `feature` as

```
sample_value                      operator_seq          actual_value
ID:Desktop|Height:627|Width:768    =,>,>         ID:Desktop|Height:600|Width:1024
ID:Desktop|Height:627|Width:768    =,>,>         ID:Desktop|Height:600|Width:600
```

`sample_value` and `actual_value` is having three sub string if we split based on `|` delimiter . and we have three operator too if we split operator based on `,` delimiter.

Now I want to compare first sub string of `sample_value` with the first  sub string of `actual_value` using first operator, second sub string of `sample_value` with the second sub string of `actual_value` using second operator and so on...

Basically the query will look like

```
if (
    (sample_value.fisrt_substr operator_seq.first_operator actual_value.first_substr) and
    (sample_value.second_substr operator_seq.second_operator actual_value.second_substr) and
    (sample_value.third_substr operator_seq.third_operator actual_value.third_substr)
) Then 1 else 0
```

so for the first row output will be 0 (because condition (Width:768 > Width:1024) is false) and for the second row output will be 1 (all three condition satisfies).

output table looks like :

```
   sample_value                 operator_seq         actual_value            result
ID:Desktop|Height:627|Width:768    =,>,>     ID:Desktop|Height:600|Width:1024   0
ID:Desktop|Height:627|Width:768    =,>,>     ID:Desktop|Height:600|Width:600    1
```

How to write the query for that.

Comment: [Evaluate conditions](http://pastebin.com/896FJfKA) Honestly it is "just for fun" solution in case if you still want to done it using pure SQL. It works for your example data but looks ugly and have some limitations (about type of the parameters for example). My suggestion is to create the stored function to calculate the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i don't know much about stored procedure. and it's urgent. So please if possible can you please suggest query for the same. Thanks again.

Comment: As said here many times: "It is not a code-writing site". If you don't know much about stored procedure then, probably, this task not for you at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function :

```
create or replace function evalBoolean(arg1 text,op text,arg2 text) returns boolean
as
$body$
declare
  result boolean;
 begin
  execute 'select $$'||arg1||'$$'||op||'$$'||arg2||'$$' into result;
  return result;
end;$body$
language plpgsql
```

And use it like this :

```
select *
  ,evalBoolean(sv[1],op[1],act[1]) and evalBoolean(sv[2],op[2],act[2]) and evalBoolean(sv[3],op[3],act[3])
  from (
     select string_to_array(sample_value,'|') sv
           ,string_to_array(operator_seq,',') op 
           ,string_to_array(actual_value,'|') act 
      from your_table
 ) a
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working. need to change a little to work for my data. You saved me. thanks again.